# Loop through variable number of tables

Tags: sqlite, loops

I run a simulation with varying number of iterations and each iteration creates an output table like table1,table2,table3... They all have the same structure like:

ID | value

but varying number of rows.

For each table, I want to compute the average of the 'value' column and show them in a new table with the column "averages" like:

tableNumber | averageValue

```
  1     |      516
  2     |      512
  3     |      521
 ...    |      ...
```

Is this possible in SQlite if the number of tables is quite high? And if not, how can I achieve this in a different way?

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating different tables, put the results in the same table, and have a column which indicates which batch or set the row belongs to. Then when you query the table you can filter on that column so that you're working only with the desired batch/set. Put an index on that column to improve the efficiency of the query and make it run faster. There will be no need to save the average results to separate tables either. Your query can produce the result without your having to persist the results as data in another table.

```
        select batch, avg(value) as AvgValue
        from simulation           
        where batch = 100
        group by batch
```

Comment: Thanks. I just got the same idea. But when the number of batches/sets is unknown, how can I loop through this unknown number and output the averages? I am sure its not hard, just can't think of it as I am quite new to databases :-)

Comment: Simply eliminate the `where batch = 100` condition.